# how to put The main diameter in magic(9) with diag in a matrix 3 * 3?

Tags: matlab, matrix

this is my code,i want to put the result of diag in a matrix 3*3 in Matlab,how   to create it?

```
a=magic(9);
b=diag(a);
```

i want to put the result of b in a matrix 3*3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by reshaping your array:

```
c=reshape(b,3,3)
```

Comment: @FarshadKhodamoradi: The code is correct. It works for every `b` with 9 elements, probably your `b` is of a different size.

Comment: Why is it that the easiest questions come around when I'm never here? lol. +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
c = reshape(b,[3,3])
```

will reshape your 1x9 matrix `b` into a 3x3 matrix `c`

Comment: but with a bit of text explaining what I do.

Comment: That would be a 3x3 and not a 9x9 matrix no?

Comment: sure. I don't mean to bother but there is a coma missing between the `b` and the first square bracket. :)

Comment: woah, that happens when you blindly and quickly rush in to answer.